# Need to install SVN on HeartInternet.co.uk web hosting

Tags: svn, ssh, backup

I am the owner of a small web design agency and I would like to secure our backups a little more by using Subversion. My idea is to have everything backed up online and be able to also recover old versions of sites we've done, etc.

I have a reseller plan at HeartInternet.co.uk, which has SSH access. How can I install SVN on it?

I know very little about Linux and servers in general, which makes my life a little harder.

Comment: Serverfault.com is a better place to ask this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://wiki.paskvil.com/index.php/Setup_a_SVN_Server_on_a_Shared_Hosting) is a pretty short and straightforward article, I'd recommend starting there and coming back if you get stuck :)

note: I did not write the article linked, but it was helpful for me in the past.